# in Pig how to find out union between two datasets or relations?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a text file which I process using some rules and come up with two separate relations

```
dump A;

A=

({(18),(17),(16),(15)})

({(4),(1)})

({(7),(6)})

({(9),(2)})

({(13),(11)})

dump B;

B = 

({(4),(3)})
```

I want to join these based on the values it holds i.e. `(4),(1)` of A and `(4),(3)` of B should join and their union should be displayed as output `(4),(1),(3)`

the output should be like this -

```
({(18),(17),(16),(15)})

({(4),(1) ,(3)})

({(7),(6)})

({(9),(2)})

({(13),(11)})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cannot use bagjoin as i dont want to join every tuples in the bag also the values won't be always in the same format. i.e. ({(4),(1)})can also come as ({(1),(4)}). 
 Also I dont want to join all, I want the join only if one of the values in a tuple match with the value in another set. like ({(4),(1)}) of A matches ({(4),(3)}) so a Union , rest all will be as is because ({(9),(2)}) of A and ({(4),(3)}) of B dont have anything in common so no match and the output will be 
({(9),(2)}).

Comment: Datafu provides a  BagLeftOuterJoin which is neither a full join nor a cross join.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bag join in datafu: http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/guide/bag-operations.html
Once joined, you can apply `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Cannot use bagjoin as i wont get tuples in the form of key value pair that i can join easily.